# Code::Block - windows.h doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, graphics, codeblocks

There is a such problem, so when I include windows.h i can draw in console mode, like fill some cell some color, can change the color of text e.g. But module windows.h can't allow me output some line or rectangle or dot, instead of that, it gives me an error `undefined reference to __imp_Rectangle`. Is there any way how to fix that problem specially for Code::Block ?
There is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    Rectangle(hdc, 100, 100, 200, 200);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Did you link with `gdi32.lib`? (Don't ask me how, I don't use CodeBlocks).

Comment: To add to @PaulSanders comment for Windows functions look up their __Requirements__ in the on-line docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle

Comment: @PaulSanders, yes, I have done this, but it still doesn`t work (it draw nothing). I even added file libgdi32.a in minGV(compiler) and linked this filename, and after that, it drew rectangle, but when I compiled code next time, it actually drew nothing.

Comment: You should add a message loop, create a window and draw in that window in response to the `WM_PAINT` message, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program